# start methode Stopwatch gives builderror C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm working on a reactiontest program in windows forms applications, and I encountered a problem with the start methode of the Stopwatch class. I'm getting a builderror, "'Form1.Stopatch' does not contain a definition for 'Start'". Here's the code where this problem occurs.

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Stopwatch extime = new Stopwatch();
        extime.Start();
    }
```

Solution:

Don't make a seperate class called stopwatch.

Comment: Do you still get the same error if you use `var extime = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();`?

Comment: No it does not work unfortunately.

Comment: Is it `Form1.Stopatch` or `Stopwatch`?

Comment: It's Form1.Stopwatch

Comment: I fixed it just by simply removing the class stopwatch that I made.

Comment: OK, so you didn't try what I asked...

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried defining your Stopwatch globally? It wold make much more sense since you will be able to control it from other Methods too. You usually won't do that in a Form's constructor (The Form is shown AFTER the constructor was called) 
And second, there is no Form1.Stopwatch at all, since Stopwatch is a class and declared (as extime) inside a method.

Btw you code works in my case, so I think the error is somewhere else.

I don't know exactly what you intend to do, but I wold do sth like:

```
Stopwatch extime;
public Form1(){
    InitializeComponent();
    extime = new Stopwatch();
    extime.Start();
}

private void Foo(){
    extime.Stop();
}
```

Comment: See OPs own question/comments for the correct answer.